# OutOfMemory Error at ListView, I try to garbage Collect but failed

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I had OutOfMemory Error when create new Activity from my ListView. I load images at listview by Picasso Library.

Is this OutOfMemory Error made by lot of bitmap Images?

I try to garbage Collect images, but I think it isn't work.

at Question.java

```
// this java file return view to adapter at adapter's getView()

public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView, int mPosition, NewsFeedListViewAdapter newsFeedListViewAdapter, final Context mContext) 
{



    try
    {
                 /**get view in here**/

    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError e) 
    {

        newsFeedListViewAdapter.recycleHalf();
        System.gc();
        return getView( inflater, convertView,  mPosition,  newsFeedListViewAdapter,  mContext) ;
    }

    newsFeedListViewAdapter.addRecycleList(
            new WeakReference<View>(
                    newsFeedQuestionViewHolder.imageview_profile_image));







    return convertView;
}
```

at NewsFeedListViewAdapter.java

```
public void recycleHalf() 
{
    int halfSize = mRecycleList.size() / 2;
    List<WeakReference<View>> recycleHalfList = mRecycleList.subList(0, halfSize);
    RecycleUtils.recursiveRecycle(recycleHalfList);

    for (int i = 0; i < halfSize; i++)
        mRecycleList.remove(0);
}


public void recycle() 
{
    RecycleUtils.recursiveRecycle(mRecycleList);
}

public void addRecycleList(WeakReference<View> view)
{
    mRecycleList.add(view);
}
```

LogCat

```
05-13 05:15:41.431: D/dalvikvm(19437): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3421K, 37% free 29306K/46496K, paused 28ms, total 29ms
05-13 05:15:41.431: I/dalvikvm-heap(19437): Grow heap (frag case) to 31.300MB for 810016-byte allocation
05-13 05:15:41.461: D/dalvikvm(19437): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 37% free 30091K/47288K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
05-13 05:15:41.511: D/dalvikvm(19437): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 37% free 30085K/47288K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
05-13 05:15:41.511: I/dalvikvm-heap(19437): Grow heap (frag case) to 34.378MB for 3240016-byte allocation
05-13 05:15:41.536: D/dalvikvm(19437): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 35% free 33249K/50456K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
05-13 05:15:41.571: D/dalvikvm(19437): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 801K, 36% free 32494K/50456K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
05-13 05:15:41.576: I/dalvikvm-heap(19437): Grow heap (frag case) to 36.630MB for 3134352-byte allocation
05-13 05:15:41.606: D/dalvikvm(19437): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 34% free 35551K/53520K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
05-13 05:15:41.626: D/dalvikvm(19437): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 34% free 35551K/53520K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
05-13 05:15:41.631: I/dalvikvm-heap(19437): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 12537360-byte allocation
05-13 05:15:41.661: D/dalvikvm(19437): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 70K, 34% free 35480K/53520K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
05-13 05:15:41.661: E/dalvikvm-heap(19437): Out of memory on a 12537360-byte allocation.
05-13 05:15:41.661: I/dalvikvm(19437): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
05-13 05:15:41.661: I/dalvikvm(19437):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x422b9578 self=0x41d6fb58
05-13 05:15:41.661: I/dalvikvm(19437):   | sysTid=19437 nice=-8 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075113980
05-13 05:15:41.661: I/dalvikvm(19437):   | state=R schedstat=( 35374459365 4630864455 68775 ) utm=3061 stm=476 core=3
05-13 05:15:41.661: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-13 05:15:41.661: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
05-13 05:15:41.661: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
05-13 05:15:41.661: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
05-13 05:15:41.661: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
05-13 05:15:41.661: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:131)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:121)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at com.zeallat.free.WriteFreeActivity.onCreate(WriteFreeActivity.java:45)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
05-13 05:15:41.666: I/dalvikvm(19437):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-13 05:15:41.666: D/skia(19437): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
05-13 05:15:41.666: D/AndroidRuntime(19437): Shutting down VM
05-13 05:15:41.666: W/dalvikvm(19437): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x422b8700)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test20140320/com.zeallat.free.WriteFreeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at com.zeallat.free.WriteFreeActivity.onCreate(WriteFreeActivity.java:45)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    ... 11 more
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    ... 26 more
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:131)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:121)
05-13 05:15:41.676: E/AndroidRuntime(19437):    ... 29 more
```

Comment: Maybe you can reduce the required memory amount by decoding the bitmap as suggested here: developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @MarkW I just erased it for look easily...

Comment: If you have an OOM error, `System.gc()` is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the image's size, i think that is the first problem.

```
05-13 05:15:41.666: D/skia(19437): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load an image of 12Mb, which is likely too big to fit in memory.

If you don't need the full definition of your image, you can use the [`BitmapFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) along with `BitmapFactory.Options` [`inSampleSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) to scale the bitmap *before* it is loaded into memory.

You can get more information in the official documentation: [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: I can use it when I use Picasso Library??

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the Picasso library provides a `resize()` method which should handle the resizing for you. You just have to calculate the dimensions (for example the width of your screen, with corresponding height)